# What does detachNode do in AVAudioEngine class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I've read the documentation and understand that using detachNode "Detaches an audio node previously attached to the audio engine". However, I am not sure what the purpose is of detaching the audio node. What happens when I detach the audio node and what does it mean? Why do you need to detach the audio node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three specific types of nodes: the output node, mixer node and the player node.

We have other nodes as well but these are the initial building block nodes.

So the engine is an object that maintains a graph of audio nodes.

You create nodes and you attach them to the engine and then you use the engine to make connections between these different audio nodes.

The engine will analyze these connections and determine which ones add up to an active chain.

When you then start the engine, audio flows through all of the active chains.

A powerful feature that the engine has is that it allows you to dynamically reconfigure these nodes.

This means that while the engine is rendering you can add new nodes and then wire them up.

And so essentially you're adding or removing chains dynamically.

So the typical workflow of the engine is that you create an instance of the engine, create instances of all the nodes you want to work with, attach them to the engine so the engine is now aware of them and then connect them together, start the engine.

This will create an active render thread and audio will flow through all of the active chains.
[From WWDC 2014](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/502)

Suppose you want to play a sound with echo effect, this is how the code will look like

```
  var audioEngine =  AVAudioEngine()

var echoNode = AVAudioUnitDelay()
echoNode.delayTime = NSTimeInterval(0.3)

var audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)

// Attach the audio effect node corresponding to the user selected effect
audioEngine.attachNode(echoNode)

// Connect Player --> AudioEffect
audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: echoNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)
// Connect AudioEffect --> Output
audioEngine.connect(echoNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)

audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler:nil)

audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)

audioPlayerNode.play()
```

And then if you want to play the audio using reverb effect:
 detach the echo node (makes the chain inactive),
 create a new reverb node,
connect the nodes again to create an active chain.

```
  audioEngine.detachNode(echoNode)
    var reverbNode = AVAudioUnitReverb()
    reverbNode.loadFactoryPreset( AVAudioUnitReverbPreset.Cathedral)
    reverbNode.wetDryMix = 60
    audioEngine.stop()
    // Attach the audio effect node corresponding to the user selected effect
    audioEngine.attachNode(reverbNode)

    // Connect Player --> AudioEffect
    audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: reverbNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)
    // Connect AudioEffect --> Output
    audioEngine.connect(reverbNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)

    audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler:nil)

    audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)

    audioPlayerNode.play()
```

Comment: Older devices can't handle the amount of nodes my app is using (works fine on newer devices). Could detaching nodes and re-attaching them as needed make sense to solve this memory issue?